# Should pom.xml be included in the war package?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, war

I got a basic (read: stupid) question:
I know pom.xml is used when creating a war-package, but my question is should the actual pom.xml be included in the war-package as well or not? and is there any good reasons why it should /shouldn't be included in the war?
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It is standard to include the POM into the WAR.

I see no immediate reason to *not* include it.